# button_to form submittal working in browser but failing rspec/capybara test with routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing integration tests using rspec and capybara for a rails4 app that cover existing functionality (I was lazy when I first wrote the app).  The following submit button works properly in the browser (Chrome) and redirects to a success page (as expected)

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= button_to "RSVP Now", new_event_attendee_path(f), :id => "open-contacts-dialog-btn", :class => "inbox-sf-add-btn tip", :style => "background:lightgreen" %>
</div>
```

But, the following test fails,

```
describe "should show confirmation message after submitting the form" do
  it "should go to success message when form submitted" do
    click_link 'See more details'
    click_button 'Sign Me Up!'
    fill_in 'Email', with: "simon@example.com"
    fill_in 'attendee_name', with: "Simon T"
    fill_in 'attendee_phone', with: "1234567890"
    fill_in 'attendee_num_guests', with: "1"
    click_on 'RSVP Now'
    page.should have_content("Awesome! You're signed up.")
  end
end
```

with the below error:

```
Failure/Error: click_on 'RSVP Now'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [POST] "/events/%23%3CActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ff9d7e003c0%3E/attendees/new"
```

My routes look like this: https://gist.github.com/srt32/6076872

I'm a bit lost because from the user perspective the action works but I can't get the test to replicate the behavior.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `button_to` is not a submit button for a standard form. Are you using it as such?

Comment: @gg_s, Yes, I'm using 'button_to' to submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a regular submit tag.

If using a form helper block:

```
<%= f.submit "RSVP Now" %>
```

Or use the standalone tag helper:

```
<%= submit_tag "RSVP Now" %>
```

Read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) on how `button_to` works. It is mainly used as links that should POST, such as actions that change data in some way. It is not for use with normal forms.